# In anylogic. in the system dynamic. i want to use if-else

Tags: dynamic, system, anylogic

The code is like
if ( evaluaterate<1){
Deliveryrate=min(Oldproduct,ForecastCan);
else
0;
}

It says that syntax errors

Comment: Looks like  you missing a brace that closes the if, and a pair around the else, as well as equating Deliveryrate to the value 0.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my comment and try to get to this:

```
if (evaluaterate<1)
{ 
  Deliveryrate=min(Oldproduct,ForecastCan); 
}
else 
{
  Deliveryrate = 0; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. It still reports syntax error. This code is for a flow in system dynamic simulation.

Comment: the error is saying   if (true) throw new RuntimeException("ERROR during variable generation:\nCouldn't parse expression for Deliveryrate - Flow: syntax error.\r\nPlease check expressions of this variable.");

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Deliveryrate=evaluaterate<1 ? min(Oldproduct,ForecastCan) : 0;
```

Comment: without the ";" at the end :)

Comment: Thanks both of you, @Benjamin,@Felipe. now it seems working.. great to have your help